# How can I ensure a radius variable doesn't get reduced below 0?

Tags: unity, c#

For some reason when I'm using the mouse to change the radius in the Update, the minimum radius is -1 even if I set the range in the top of the script to be 0,50 and even if I check that the xradius is be 0 or higher it's still getting to -1.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;

    public bool circle = true;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float xradius = 15;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float yradius = 15;
    LineRenderer line;

    public float drawSpeed = 0.3f;

    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.positionCount = (segments + 1);
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (xradius >= 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0)
            {
                xradius = xradius + 1;
                CreatePoints();
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0)
            {
                xradius = xradius - 1;
                CreatePoints();
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreatePoints()
    {
        if (circle == true)
            yradius = xradius;

        float x;
        float z;

        float change = 2 * (float)Math.PI / segments;
        float angle = change;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition((int)i, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, z));

            angle += change;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Update I did:

```
if (xradius >= 0)
```

But yet when using the mouse for the minimum radius it set both xradius and yradius in the sliders to -1 not sure how can it be -1 if I set the range in both xradius and yradius to be 0,50

You can see in the screenshot in the Inspector in the right both Xradius and Yradius are -1

[image: Radius -1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that using a `Range` to limit a variable is something **inspector-only**! That means that if in the `Update` you did something like `xradius = 100` it would work. `Range` is for convenience only and is in no way restricting.

Based on your update, it seems that nothing happens when `xradius` drops below 0. That means by moving your mouse around, it can get a variety of values (including above 50 and below 0), but once it hits -1, it gets stuck, and there is no way for the value to change again.

There are many ways to fix that, one of them is limiting the value of `xradius` the moment you change it, something like:

```
if (xradius < 50) xradius++; // Ensures that xradius is always <= 50

...

if (xradius > 0) xradius--; // Ensures that radius is always >= 0
```

To avoid errors, as suggested by [Bilkokuya](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/111144/bilkokuya), it would be better to `xradius = 50` or `xradius = 0` after you change its value, to ensure it is within range. Or alternatively use a min/max function `xradius = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Min(50, xradius), 0)`

Or as a one liner, as pointed out by [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory), you can use `Mathf.Clamp(radius + change, minRadius, maxRadius)` like so:

```
// where `change` in your case is either +1 or -1
xradius = Mathf.Clamp(xradius +change, 0, 50);
```